# Examples of beautiful statewide maps that have a lot of layers (20+ layers)

Tags: visualisation

I'm in the process of building a statewide map of all the transportation modes, waterways, and other information for a whopping total of 40 layers.

I was wondering if you have seen print maps that have many displayed layers in a professional and beautiful manner, and if you can share them, or at least provide some of the design aspects that made the map so "pretty".

My question is different from [beautiful maps](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3083/examples-of-beautiful-maps) as I'm only interested in printing them and not putting them on the web

Answer (score 2):

That is a tough question to answer in a forum. I have many printed maps that have many layers. It does take quite a bit of diligence to create and manage these documents after the initial creation. I use many varied techniques to layer and overlay information. As a for instance... labeling items in the same layer with differing labels requires utilizing sql, sometimes adding a new field to theme on, a lot of finess to make sure they don't overpost or get dropped, and finally patience. My software has a pause label button. However most of the time I prefer to wait (sometimes 4-5mins) for a redraw with labels because inevitably I will finalize my map and hit print only to discover I had the labels paused! (which means they don't print!!!). In many cases I have two copies of each layer one for the map (with thick visible lines/symbols to make it pop) and one for the legend (which needs a nice thin line to keep from overrunning the label). Managing all of this and managing layer naming, and document naming requires either a lot of diligence or some pretty thin hair. Pretty maps are a completely 'nother story. 
Just pray they don't say politically correct color scheme.

[image: using transparency, color schemes, and patterns]

Comment: Ack, I have a negative gut reaction whenever I see hatching in a GIS context.  I can let it pass for CAD, but not GIS.

Comment: Not bad enough to earn a down-vote, though.  Maybe you could give an explanation for the hatching?

Comment: when the boss says show me everything and you get to the third layer overlap something has to give. I already explained pretty is not in this picture. This is about readability and funtional information. explanation for hatching is that you can see through it. ;-) sorry for the ugly factor. Just trying to make a point. When you think about the uses of coordinate systems (measurement, and aesthetics) there is a give and take. That is what I think of when someone says they want to put 40 layers on a printed map.

Comment: this is from an 87" tall wall map, it is a small piece but I thought it would illustrate the point.