# Seeking examples of Beautiful Maps at county level or closer?

Tags: cartography, county

I was wondering if anyone else had similar examples to [Seeking examples of beautiful maps?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3083/examples-of-beautiful-maps), but at a county or parcel level.

At those levels, I wonder if people will react the same, or if there will be other facts to consider at that resolution.

Comment: perhaps your and my questions should be combined http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3396/examples-of-beautiful-statewide-maps-that-have-a-lot-of-layers-20-layers

Answer (score 6):

Eduard Imhof’s Schweizerischer Mittelschulatlas is probably the best example of applied beautiful cartography ever.

[image: alt Imhof]

Codex99 has a very good presentation of him and his work here: [Imhof wie ein Kartographische Rockstar](http://www.codex99.com/cartography/71.html)

Answer (score 2):

[Orienteering maps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orienteering_map) are good example of high scale maps. Very small features are represented on such maps, with a very detailed representation.

The way to make such maps is rather well formalised in [this document](http://orienteering.org/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/International-Specification-for-Orienteering-Maps-2000.pdf).

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but im not a fan of this.
Maybe cos I cant see the legend properly, but no idea whats going on.  What are the numbers all about for a start?

Comment: The route the runners need to follow I expect.

Answer (score 1):

Ordnance Survey 1:25,000 scale mapping (known as Explorer Series)

[image]

Continuous across England,Wales and Scotland

Comment: Maybe it is the reproduction, but it doesn't look very "sharp" to me.

Comment: The online version is a much lower resolution (72dpi) compared to the purchased tiffs (lzw compressed) are at 600 dpi.

Answer (score 0):

I love the [Rand Mcnally](http://www.randmcnally.com/) maps. I suggest going to the local bookstore or gas station and checking them out. they're usually packed with lots of information and done in a very nice way