# Making beautiful maps in R?

Tags: r, cartography

There are quite some nice possibilities to analyse spatial data in R and in the context of my current project I would like to use R more frequently to do that.

Until now I plot my maps with ggplot2 package that brings a lot of practical tools to plot and explore data. Still my maps are not nearly as good looking as the ones I used to plot in ArcGIS.

So for publishing purposes I wonder if there are any good tutorials, books, practical tips, packages etc. that I could use to experiment a little bit and make my maps more good looking?

Comment: Not sure..but might be useful for you http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3083/examples-of-beautiful-maps/45518#45518

Comment: @Sunil These are great resources for R cartography - lots of useful code one can adapt and buid upon. You should add it as an answer.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In addition to the ones posted [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3083/examples-of-beautiful-maps/45518#45518), in the R gallery website there are a few examples:

- http://gallery.r-enthusiasts.com/graph/SuperStorm_Sandy_170
- http://gallery.r-enthusiasts.com/RGraphGallery.php?graph=146
- http://gallery.r-enthusiasts.com/RGraphGallery.php?graph=113

---

other websites with tutorials and good mapping examples in R:

- http://www.molecularecologist.com/2012/09/making-maps-with-r/
- http://www.r-bloggers.com/create-maps-with-maptools-r-package/
- http://procomun.wordpress.com/2012/02/18/maps_with_r_1/
- http://www.nceas.ucsb.edu/scicomp/usecases/CreateMapsWithRGraphics

I hope this helps. The last one gives you one example with vector data and another with satellite imagery, while the r-bloggers has many other mapping examples with R.

Comment: thank you for the links. the ucsb tutorial seems really interesting and cover some of the important basic operations.

Comment: @A.R first link appears to be dead.

Comment: Could you please edit the answer to update/remove the dead links?

Comment: A compendium of useful information, it's a shame it has been closed. There been some really great R mapping advances recently.

Answer (score 9):

According to your question the very good example is on [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3083/examples-of-beautiful-maps/45518#45518) link . This link contains various beautiful map collections using R software . I am sure this will help you!!. I am also referring above site for reference.

Comment: these are really beautifull maps. especially the London cycle hire. The code is fully provided. Some of the maps miss some basic features (legend, scale, northarrow etc.) but from a asthetic point of view they are great. thanks.

Answer (score 7):

The ebook  ["Data mashups in R"](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920018438.do?sortby=publicationDate) is just 40 Pages long and will walk you through an example project (mapping foreclosures in Washington DC)

From the first reader-review :

> This book presents an interesting project, drawing together a number
>   of data sources and geocoding them.

I've once skimmed the PDF, want to have a closer look someday. It's on my to-do list.

Comment: thank you for the link. I've just checked out the book. It seems quite interesting and it's for free :) not that much layout advices though.

Answer (score 5):

I have found a nice example R-script with several demonstrations of packages, map styling and also basic GIS operations. Maybe this'll come in handy for some readers.

[Using R as a GIS](https://sites.google.com/site/rodriguezsanchezf/news/usingrasagis)

Answer (score 1):

If somebody is still following. Here you can find a huge amount of tutorials and links on diffrent mapping themes in R:

http://spatialanalysis.co.uk/r/

and for some basic stuff like legend, scalebar and north-arrow look at the code here: http://spatialanalysis.co.uk/2010/09/rmaps/