# Plotting map in R that looks old (yellowish and stained)?

Tags: r, cartography, color, plot

I want to make a map in R that appear old (yellowish and stained). For example:

[image]

Is it possible to achieve this effect entirely within R rather than bringing a map into an image processing program such as Illustrator or Photoshop?

Comment: Wouldn't it be quicker to save as a common image type format then modify it inside a Photoshop/Gimp tool ?

Comment: There might be some insight here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/48828/making-beautiful-maps-in-r

Comment: @gisnside That's a good idea, though some small letters could become unreadable. Maybe a mix of old looking/legible text may be preferable.

Comment: I'm no R expert but as a suggestion, you could maybe make an old looking image in a image software then reference it below your vector and text items. After that, you make your R analysis on top of it ? Or you switch to a gis software like QGIS :D

Comment: @gisnside That's an even better idea, since I wouldn't have to redo all steps in Gimp after every change in R. And no, I prefer R, because once the script is done, I can do something else while R runs (in QGIS I would have to do many clicks every time a single thing changes). And R serves for many other things beyond maps.

Comment: @Rodrigo you can create a script in R and call a PyQgis script to make the map inside the same script

Comment: You can make a transparent map in R and use the `magick` package to overlay it on to a "parchment" base. You don't need other tools as others are crazily suggesting.

Comment: How bout [this](https://github.com/mtennekes/tmap/tree/master/demo/ClassicMap)? It uses a predefined layout option called `tm_style_classic()`. The `tmap` package is the best option for producing quality maps in R in my opinion.

Comment: I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  If you are just looking for ideas we provide a place to do that in the [GIS Chat Room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/939/gis).  Which "somebody had made it before"?

Comment: @hrbrmstr Please consider adding your comment as an answer, hopefully with a few lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

Following @gisnside comment, I produced an "old paper look" image in Gimp (following [this tutorial](https://www.cartographersguild.com/attachment.php?s=1fb2314b9172ffefca6e3cca8bcb3ab1&attachmentid=338&d=1178255480) from [this thread](https://www.cartographersguild.com/showthread.php?t=533)). Then I added it as a PNG image inside R (using readPNG from library `png` and rasterImage from `graphics`). Then all I had to do was draw over the image.

Below is the map produced (still needing some adjustments, but you get the idea).

[image: Estrada Real]