# How to create a value-by-alpha map in Java?

Tags: cartography, java, geotiff-tiff, geotools, visualisation

Someone has post similar question as mine before : [similar question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2784/how-to-implement-value-by-alpha-map-in-gis)

But my objective is slightly different.

I have a `shape file (.shp)` (a country map)

I would like to write a piece of java code to create a value-by-alpha map like below:

[image: Example]

Do anyone know is there any java library to do this?

Can GeoTool do this? If can, then how?

Answer (score 1):

You can create maps using value by alpha using SLD - (the point being that WA has a lower unemployment rate than OR but has more people so it appears more solid).

[image: Unemployment (alpha proportional to Population.]

The trick is to use an expression in the fill-opacity element. If you add the SLD file below to a standard GeoServer install you can see the topp:states layer rendered.

In GeoTools it is even easier as you can use any function you like to set the fill opacity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.0.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd">
    <NamedLayer>
        <Name>USA states Unemployment</Name>
        <UserStyle>
            <Name>Unemployment</Name>
            <Title>Unemploymentin the United States</Title>
            <Abstract>A sample filter that filters the United States into three
        categories of unemployment, drawn in different colors</Abstract>
            <FeatureTypeStyle>
                <Rule>
                    <Title>&lt; 5%</Title>
                    <ogc:Filter>
                        <ogc:PropertyIsLessThan>
                            <ogc:Mul>           
                                <ogc:Div>
                                    <ogc:PropertyName>UNEMPLOY</ogc:PropertyName>
                                    <ogc:Add>
                                        <ogc:PropertyName>EMPLOYED</ogc:PropertyName>
                                        <ogc:PropertyName>UNEMPLOY</ogc:PropertyName>
                                    </ogc:Add>
                                </ogc:Div>
                                <ogc:Literal>100</ogc:Literal>
                            </ogc:Mul>  
                            <ogc:Literal>5</ogc:Literal>
                        </ogc:PropertyIsLessThan>
                    </ogc:Filter>
                    <PolygonSymbolizer>
                        <Stroke>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke-width">0.2</CssParameter>
                        </Stroke>

                        <Fill>
                            <!-- CssParameters allowed are fill (the color) and fill-opacity -->
                            <CssParameter name="fill">#4DFF4D</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="fill-opacity">
                                <ogc:Div>
                                    <ogc:PropertyName>PERSONS</ogc:PropertyName>
                                    <ogc:Literal>30e6</ogc:Literal>
                                </ogc:Div>
                            </CssParameter>
                        </Fill>     
                    </PolygonSymbolizer>
                    <TextSymbolizer>
                        <Label>

                            <ogc:PropertyName>STATE_ABBR</ogc:PropertyName>
                            <![CDATA[
                                ]]>
                            <ogc:Function name="numberFormat">
                                <ogc:Literal>#.##</ogc:Literal>
                                <ogc:Mul>           
                                    <ogc:Div>
                                        <ogc:PropertyName>UNEMPLOY</ogc:PropertyName>
                                        <ogc:Add>
                                            <ogc:PropertyName>EMPLOYED</ogc:PropertyName>
                                            <ogc:PropertyName>UNEMPLOY</ogc:PropertyName>
                                        </ogc:Add>
                                    </ogc:Div>
                                    <ogc:Literal>100</ogc:Literal>
                                </ogc:Mul>  
                            </ogc:Function>

                        </Label>
                        <Font>
                            <CssParameter name="font-family">Times New Roman</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="font-style">Normal</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="font-size">14</CssParameter>
                        </Font>
                        <LabelPlacement>
                            <PointPlacement>
                                <AnchorPoint>
                                    <AnchorPointX>0.5</AnchorPointX>
                                    <AnchorPointY>0.5</AnchorPointY>
                                </AnchorPoint>
                            </PointPlacement>
                        </LabelPlacement>
                    </TextSymbolizer>
                </Rule>
                <Rule>
                    <Title>5-7%</Title>
                    <ogc:Filter>
                        <ogc:PropertyIsBetween>
                            <ogc:Mul>           
                                <ogc:Div>
                                    <ogc:PropertyName>UNEMPLOY</ogc:PropertyName>
                                    <ogc:Add>
                                        <ogc:PropertyName>EMPLOYED</ogc:PropertyName>
                                        <ogc:PropertyName>UNEMPLOY</ogc:PropertyName>
                                    </ogc:Add>
                                </ogc:Div>
                                <ogc:Literal>100</ogc:Literal>
                            </ogc:Mul>  
                            <ogc:LowerBoundary>
                                <ogc:Literal>5</ogc:Literal>
                            </ogc:LowerBoundary>
                            <ogc:UpperBoundary>
                                <ogc:Literal>7</ogc:Literal>
                            </ogc:UpperBoundary>
                        </ogc:PropertyIsBetween>
                    </ogc:Filter>
                    <PolygonSymbolizer>
                        <Stroke>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke-width">0.2</CssParameter>
                        </Stroke>

                        <Fill>
                            <!-- CssParameters allowed are fill (the color) and fill-opacity -->
                            <CssParameter name="fill">#FF4D4D</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="fill-opacity">
                                <ogc:Div>
                                    <ogc:PropertyName>PERSONS</ogc:PropertyName>
                                    <ogc:Literal>30e6</ogc:Literal>
                                </ogc:Div>
                            </CssParameter>

                        </Fill>     
                    </PolygonSymbolizer>
                    <TextSymbolizer>
                        <Label>

                            <ogc:PropertyName>STATE_ABBR</ogc:PropertyName>
                            <![CDATA[
                                ]]>
                            <ogc:Function name="numberFormat">
                                <ogc:Literal>#.##</ogc:Literal>
                                <ogc:Mul>           
                                    <ogc:Div>
                                        <ogc:PropertyName>UNEMPLOY</ogc:PropertyName>
                                        <ogc:Add>
                                            <ogc:PropertyName>EMPLOYED</ogc:PropertyName>
                                            <ogc:PropertyName>UNEMPLOY</ogc:PropertyName>
                                        </ogc:Add>
                                    </ogc:Div>
                                    <ogc:Literal>100</ogc:Literal>
                                </ogc:Mul>  
                            </ogc:Function>

                        </Label>
                        <Font>
                            <CssParameter name="font-family">Times New Roman</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="font-style">Normal</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="font-size">14</CssParameter>
                        </Font>
                        <LabelPlacement>
                            <PointPlacement>
                                <AnchorPoint>
                                    <AnchorPointX>0.5</AnchorPointX>
                                    <AnchorPointY>0.5</AnchorPointY>
                                </AnchorPoint>
                            </PointPlacement>
                        </LabelPlacement>
                    </TextSymbolizer>
                </Rule>
                <Rule>
                    <Title>&gt; 7%</Title>
                    <!-- like a linesymbolizer but with a fill too -->
                    <ogc:Filter>
                        <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
                            <ogc:Mul>           
                                <ogc:Div>
                                    <ogc:PropertyName>UNEMPLOY</ogc:PropertyName>
                                    <ogc:Add>
                                        <ogc:PropertyName>EMPLOYED</ogc:PropertyName>
                                        <ogc:PropertyName>UNEMPLOY</ogc:PropertyName>
                                    </ogc:Add>
                                </ogc:Div>
                                <ogc:Literal>100</ogc:Literal>
                            </ogc:Mul>  
                            <ogc:Literal>7</ogc:Literal>
                        </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
                    </ogc:Filter>
                    <PolygonSymbolizer>
                        <Stroke>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke-width">0.2</CssParameter>
                        </Stroke>

                        <Fill>
                            <!-- CssParameters allowed are fill (the color) and fill-opacity -->
                            <CssParameter name="fill">#4D4DFF</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="fill-opacity">
                                <ogc:Div>
                                    <ogc:PropertyName>PERSONS</ogc:PropertyName>
                                    <ogc:Literal>30e6</ogc:Literal>
                                </ogc:Div>
                            </CssParameter>

                        </Fill>     
                    </PolygonSymbolizer>
                    <TextSymbolizer>
                        <Label>

                            <ogc:PropertyName>STATE_ABBR</ogc:PropertyName>
                            <![CDATA[
                                ]]>
                            <ogc:Function name="numberFormat">
                                <ogc:Literal>#.##</ogc:Literal>
                                <ogc:Mul>           
                                    <ogc:Div>
                                        <ogc:PropertyName>UNEMPLOY</ogc:PropertyName>
                                        <ogc:Add>
                                            <ogc:PropertyName>EMPLOYED</ogc:PropertyName>
                                            <ogc:PropertyName>UNEMPLOY</ogc:PropertyName>
                                        </ogc:Add>
                                    </ogc:Div>
                                    <ogc:Literal>100</ogc:Literal>
                                </ogc:Mul>  
                            </ogc:Function>

                        </Label>
                        <Font>
                            <CssParameter name="font-family">Times New Roman</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="font-style">Normal</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="font-size">14</CssParameter>
                        </Font>
                        <LabelPlacement>
                            <PointPlacement>
                                <AnchorPoint>
                                    <AnchorPointX>0.5</AnchorPointX>
                                    <AnchorPointY>0.5</AnchorPointY>
                                </AnchorPoint>
                            </PointPlacement>
                        </LabelPlacement>
                    </TextSymbolizer>
                </Rule>
                <Rule>
                    <Title>Boundary</Title>
                    <LineSymbolizer>
                    </LineSymbolizer>

                </Rule>
            </FeatureTypeStyle>
        </UserStyle>
    </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```